# Marginal effects in a Probit Model

Tags: regression, econometrics, regression-coefficients, probit

The exact problem I am trying to solve is as follows. I have a Probit specification:

$$ P_t = \Phi(\beta^T x_t) $$

where $\Phi$ is a standard normal CDF and $x$ is a matrix of independent variables measured at time $t$. $P$ is the probability of success.

I am trying to calculate the marginal effect of change in each $x$ over the probability. Formally:

I have two estimates estimated at different time points:
$$ P_t = \Phi(\beta^T x_t) \quad ... (1)$$ and
$$ P_{t+1} = \Phi(\beta^T x_{t+1}) \quad ... (2)$$

I want to get the weighted impact of each change in $x$ that is $\Delta x = x_{t+1}-x_t$ over the difference in the probability of success $\Delta P = P_{t+1} - P_t$. In simple linear regression, this is easy as the marginal impact was the coefficient multiplied by the absolute change in the variable.

I have already tried to calculate the marginal probability effect:

$$\frac {\partial P_t} {\partial x_{it}} = \beta_i \phi(\beta^T x_t) \quad ... (3)$$

and then take a simple difference:
$$\frac {\partial P_{t+1}} {\partial x_{i \ t+1}} - \frac {\partial P_t} {\partial x_{it}}$$
where $\phi$ is the standard normal PDF. However, the problem with this approach is that the marginal effect is a function of every independent variable. Suppose, $x_{it} = x_{i \ t+1}$ then the marginal impact would be non-zero if any other $x_j$ changed. This should intuitively be zero as the driver did not change at all.

Any insights or sources would be much appreciated. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: How is this different than any other model? I.e. if one variable remains the same, but others change the predicted value changes with any model.

Comment: The marginal probability effect in a Probit model is also function of all other variables. See the equation 3 above

Comment: I have answered another version of the same question [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/74735/interpretation-of-coefficients-of-a-probit-model/74742#74742).